# It's possible to upload a image which is not located in eclipse project to a jsp

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

Is there a way to upload an image not located in Eclipse project to a jsp?. I have searched that it is possible if image directory is placed in Application Server but that's not what I want, I would like to use a c:\directory in Windows 7. Please find below the code in jsp file I'm using:

```
<body>

<h1>Image below:</h1>

<img alt="No Image"     
src="C:/MauricioFiles/Proyectos_JavaEE7/MusicStore/pics/guitar.png"   
width="100" height="100">

</body>
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<img src>` must refer a public web URL, not a local disk file system path. Your images have to be available by a HTTP request. It's namely the webbrowser who has got to download them, not the webserver who has got to include them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upload it. But I think what you want to do is to access the local file without uploading it.

But as JSP says, Java**Server** Pages. That means that you need to have all your files uploaded and ready in your server. What you do at the moment is, that you use a file which is on your computer and not inside your Server-directory. But you can't access local files outside of your server-environment.